# Landing page with Express and nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, express, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just bought a HTML landing page and I am totally newbie with all of this...

There are 3 different folders :
/windows /ios /android

How can I use nodejs and express to display the landing page?
I mean, how to redirect the client to /ios if he uses an iPhone for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Detuned posted some really good links that answer your question.

Basically, you'd want to check the `userAgent` and render a page based on where they're coming from.

The `userAgent` names aren't correct, or shouldn't be since i've not checked them but i'd expect something similar to this :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  var userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'];

  if (userAgent.startsWith('Mozilla') || userAgent.startsWith('Chrome') || userAgent.startsWith('Explorer')) {

      res.render('index_windows', {})

  } else if (userAgent.startsWith('iOS')) {

      res.render('index_ios', {})

  } else if (userAgent.startsWith('android')) {
      res.render('index_android', {})
  }
  else {
   res.render('index_windows', {})
  }
});
```

This basically grabs the `/` which is your home url like `www.example.com/` and does a check on the headers to determine where the user has come from.

Comment: Ok I see. But in the case of the `userAgent` does not match Mozilla, iOS or android?

Comment: @Thomi sorry, yes, you'd just add a `else` at the end, anything that doesn't match will render your default template so maybe, `index_windows`

Comment: last question, what are `index_windows/android/ios`? path to each index? how do you declare this type of static variable?

Comment: There the `views` so within within the folder name `views` you typically have `index.html` or `index.jade` whatever templating language you're using and `user.jade` so the `res.render('index_windows', {})` would be rendering a file in the view called `index_windows`. I assumed within the different folders you had an `index.html` page for them all, so you can add them into the `views` directory

Comment: So I need jade module?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of going about this: you would detect the browser/platform type on the client side ([here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)) or server side ([here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306576)). You would, then, send that information over to the server side so that you can render the appropriate static assets based on that information.

For rendering static assets in Node.js, refer [here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)